# Two Google_Client objects in the same script

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-api-php-client, google-client

I'm trying to create two Google_MirrorService objects on the same script: one to send a timeline card to one user and other to update other user timeline card. The problem is that when I create those objects, I have to use two different Google_Client objects. When I create the second Google_Client object, then the first Google_MirrorService get broken. After trying to discover what's happening, I discover that Google_Client uses static vars (static $auth, static $io, static $cache and static $useBatch). I think that the problem because second Google_Client object overwrites those static vars on first object.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks kindly

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code and which php library version you're using?

Comment: I don't think there is anyway around creating two, if you want access to them both at the sometime.  A single client object cant have access to two different users at the same time.